# How to install and setup s3fs on OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: macos, command-line, aws

I installed [`s3fs`](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/), a tool that allows mounting Amazon S3 buckets as a file system. I created folder for mounting in `/mnt/s3` then I created a file in `/etc/passwd-s3fs` with the content `BucketName:AccessKeyId:SecretAccessKey`
but I still can't access it, and the error is:

> s3fs: could not determine how to establish security credentials

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at the code, if it cannot parse the credential file in its default location, it silently falls through to that error. But, if you put that same file's path into the environment variable AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE or pass on the command line, it will report "is not readable" if it fails to parse.

Comment: Hi Tim, Could you please give me more explanation ?

Comment: and now the error is "s3fs: specified passwd_file is not readable", do you know what is that mean ?

Comment: The code opens a stream to read the file. Before it passes the stream to the method that reads the content, it checks for errors on the stream. My guess is that the user trying to mount doesn't have permission to read the file. Try running "chmod 666 /etc/passwd-s3fs" to make it world readable to debug. Then be sure to set ownership and permissions to something more reasonable from a security perspective. (anyone reading your credentials from that file can then use your AWS S3 account)

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon `s3fs` you have two options for credentials: `root` or per user.

For a `root` setup you would place your credentials in here:

```
/etc/passwd-s3fs
```

And then make sure the permissions to that file are `640` like this:

```
sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs
```

The contents of that file should simply be `[AccessKey]:[SuperSecretKey]` with those two values substituted for your real access key and super secret key. Note I did not prefix the “bucket” name as you have in your example. I would recommend just seeing if you can access the S3 stuff to begin with for testing.

If you want to do user level credentials, that would be placed in the home folder of the user who would need to have `s3fs` access. So it would if this were for you, it would be in here:

```
nano ~/.passwd-s3fs
```

The contents of the file would be the same as `/etc/passwd-s3fs` but the permissions would be different. So make sure those permissions are `600` like this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.passwd-s3fs
```

Then as far as mounting goes, this is how you would mount the contents if you are `root`:

```
sudo s3fs [BucketName] /mnt/s3
```

Be sure to change the bucket name to match the actual bucket you wish to mount. And to run that on a per user basis using the `~/.passwd-s3fs` credentials, just run the same command without `sudo` like this:

```
s3fs [BucketName] /mnt/s3
```

To unmount the mounted bucket, just do this:

```
sudo umount /mnt/s3
```

Or do this if you are using a per-user setup:

```
umount /mnt/s3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it opens a stream to read the file. Before it passes that stream to the method that reads the content, it checks for errors on the stream. My guess is that the user trying to mount doesn't have permission to read the file.

The right way to fix this is to give that config file the proper ownership and permissions if you can determine what it should be. If you cannot, you can open up the permissions to make it readable by everyone ***as a test***.

Try running `chmod 666 /etc/passwd-s3fs` to make it world readable and see if that allows you to mount. Note that some programs (such as OpenSSH) are written to warn or fail if config files have permissions that are not restrictive enough. I only looked quickly, but didn't see that in `s3fs`.

Once you confirm the config file is correct, you must then set ownership and permissions to something more reasonable from a security perspective. Anyone reading your credentials from that file can then use your AWS S3 account.

Comment: yes you right, and thanks to you now I can mount my folder, but another problem, after pass your instructions above and I list my mount folder, that exist, and the result is : (s3fs@fuse0 on /mnt/s3 (fuse4x, synchronous) ), but when i wish to list /mnt/s3, the result (ls: /mnt/s3: No such file or directory), so any idea with this ?

Comment: it is because mounting point previllage on fstab ? but I can't figure to change fstb on lion, I alredy tried use (sudo vifs) but it does'nt change anyting. i don;t know